# How can I create a function that takes a parameter of unknown type in C?

Tags: c, types

Say I have the following code:

```
struct test* t1;
t1 = get_t(1);
```

... where `get_t` is:

```
struct test* get_t(int);
```

How can I refactor the above code and put it in a function? Something like the following:

```
void r1(?* t, ?* (fn*)(int)) {
    t = fn(1);
}

/* ... */

struct test* t1;
r1(t1, &get_t);
```

Comment: Well you could use `void r1(struct test* t, struct test* (fn*)(int))`... why is the parameter of unknown type?

Comment: Because I want to use the same function for a, say, `struct another_test`. Just as I have `struct test* t1` and use `r1(t1, &get_t)`, I want to be able to also have `struct another_test* t2` and use `r1(t2, &get_at)`, where `get_at` returns `struct another_test*`, and does the same things to obtain it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `void *param`, a pointer to anything ... commonly used in glib as `gpointer`

Comment: If I define `r1` as `void r1(void* t, void* (fn*)(int))`, then the compiler complains that I'm not giving it the correct function, since my `get_t` function returns a `struct test*`.

Comment: `get_t` needs to return `void *` as well.

Comment: @rdineiu: You'll need to change your get_t function appropriately too.  The signature needs to change but your implementation may assume that the parameters are the type you needed.

Comment: Aha, so the only way to do this is to make `get_t` return a `void*`?

Comment: That's the only way I know and they way I always see this issue to be solved.

Comment: Void pointers is indeed the only way to write complete generic code in C. It should also be noted that the only case where you actually need to write such generic code, is when designing abstract code modules, such as ADTs and search/sort algoritms. If you find yourself needing completely generic code in any other situation, you should probably reconsider your program design.

Comment: Should be `void **t` argument and `*t = fn(1);` assignment.  Usage is then `r1(&t1,&get_t)` so that t1 is assigned to.

Comment: @drawnonward feel free to edit the answer and improve it. Cheers !

Comment: @Lundin, I found myself repeating the same code in many functions, and I need to DRY it up. So I wanted to extract it in another function. If this was OOP, I would have extended a class in which I would define a method to do this. An alternative would be a macro, but that is a very ugly solution.

Comment: @Lundin, it would remove code repetition (DRY), and that's what I meant by DRY. It's not for readability, but for maintainability. But I agree with you, if that requires using void pointers, then it's most likely not worth it.

Answer (score 5):

I have two ideas:

[1] Pass `void` pointer to the variable/object, and type cast it in the function.

[2] Make a union of all datatypes along with an integer datatype which will identify which datatype variable in the union does hold the actual data. Pass this union as value or as `void *`

```
struct _unknown {
   union {
      int a;
      float b;
      char c;
      double d;
   } data;
   int type;
} unknown;
.
.
.
if (unknown.type == FLOAT)
{
  /* Process variable b */ 
}
else if (unknown.type == INT)
{
 /* Process variable a */
}
.
. 
.
```

Something like this.

You can hash define the `FLOAT` and `INT` and others as unique values.

Or simply

```
struct _unknown {
  void *data;
  int type;
} unknown;
.
.
.
if (unknown == FLOAT)
{
  /* process (float *) data */
}
else if (unknown == INT)
{
  /* process (int *) data */
}
else if (unknown == MY_DATA_TYPE)
{
  /* process (my_data_type *) data */
  /* where my_data_type could be a typedef, or struct */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have gcc, you can use this more typesafe version:

```
#define r1(varp,func) ({ \
    typeof(**varp)* (*_func_)(int); \
    typeof(**varp)* _varp_ = (varp); \
    _func_ = (func); \
    r1_((void**)(_varp_),(void*(*)(int))_func_); \
    })

void r1_(void** varp,void*(*func)(int))
    {
    *varp = func(1);
    }
```

Call as:

```
struct test* get_t(int);
struct test* t1;
r1(&t,get_t);
```

(You dont need to use `&` on functions, they decay to pointers automatically, like arrays). This checks that `t` is a pointer, and that `get_t` is a function returning that type of pointer. `_varp_` is technically unneeded, but keeps the argument evaluation in the right order.

#### Edit:

If you don't have gcc, you can still do this, but you have to provide the type explicitly:

```
#define r1(T,varp,func) do { \
    T*(*_func_)(int); \
    T* _varp_ = (varp); \
    _func_ = (func); \
    r1_((void**)(_varp_),(void*(*)(int))_func_); \
    } while(0)

void r1_(void** varp,void*(*func)(int))
    {
    *varp = func(1);
    }
```

Call as:

```
struct test* get_t(int);
struct test* t1;
r1(struct test*,&t,get_t);
```

not quite as safe, and more redundant, but still fairly good.